# Electron child window is not inheriting zoom level of parent window

Tags: electron

In my application, user can open multiple child windows, for that I've implemented below code:

```
var currentZoom = win.webContents.getZoomFactor();
const window = new BrowserWindow({
  title: data.windowName,
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  frame: true,
  autoHideMenuBar: true,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    contextIsolation: false,
    zoomFactor: currentZoom
  }
});

window.loadURL(
  url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/../../dist/zinniax-chat-frontend/index.html`),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true,
    hash: `/popout-window?data=${encodeURIComponent(queryParams)}`
  })
);

childWindow[unique_key] = window;  // I'm maintaing an array of child windows
```

Here, I'm fetching zoom level of the parent window `win`.

So, for the first time it works fine. Let say in parent window, I'm zooming to level 4, and then opening the child window. So child window gets level 4 zoom. But when I reset the main window to level 1 zoom and reopen the child window, it still opens at level 4. This happens even after I completely closes the app and opening again. Does browser window caches the zoom factor? How to resolve this?

Here is how I make changes to zoom level of parent and child windows:

```
win.webContents.on('zoom-changed', (event, zoomDirection) => {
  var currentZoom = win.webContents.getZoomFactor();

  if (zoomDirection === 'in') {
    // win.webContents.setZoomFactor(currentZoom + 0.20);
    win.webContents.zoomFactor = currentZoom + 0.2;

    for (var key of Object.keys(childWindow)) {
      if (!childWindow[key].isDestroyed()) {
        childWindow[key].webContents.zoomFactor = currentZoom + 0.2;
      }
    }
  }
  if (zoomDirection === 'out') {
    // win.webContents.setZoomFactor(currentZoom - 0.20);
    if (currentZoom >= 0.4) {
      win.webContents.zoomFactor = currentZoom - 0.2;

      for (var key of Object.keys(childWindow)) {
        if (!childWindow[key].isDestroyed()) {
          childWindow[key].webContents.zoomFactor = currentZoom - 0.2;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

ipcMain.on('zoomIn', () => {
  var currentZoom = win.webContents.getZoomFactor();
  win.webContents.zoomFactor = currentZoom + 0.2;
  for (var key of Object.keys(childWindow)) {
    if (!childWindow[key].isDestroyed()) {
      childWindow[key].webContents.zoomFactor = currentZoom + 0.2;
    }
  }
});

ipcMain.on('zoomOut', () => {
  var currentZoom = win.webContents.getZoomFactor();
  if (currentZoom >= 0.4) {
    win.webContents.zoomFactor = currentZoom - 0.2;

    for (var key of Object.keys(childWindow)) {
      if (!childWindow[key].isDestroyed()) {
        childWindow[key].webContents.zoomFactor = currentZoom - 0.2;
      }
    }
  }
});

ipcMain.on('zoomReset', () => {
  win.webContents.zoomFactor = 1.0;
  for (var key of Object.keys(childWindow)) {
    if (!childWindow[key].isDestroyed()) {
      childWindow[key].webContents.zoomFactor = 1.0;
    }
  }
});
```